# How to fetch data from a hyperlink in in an object of arrays and return the result?

Tags: redux, async-await, redux-toolkit

My backend returns the following data. For some data there is a hyperlink that i need to fetch in order to get the data. While that is for an single object quite straight forward. I struggle how i get the data out an array of objects.

```
 {
      count: 2,
      next: null,
      previous: null,
      results: [
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Story-2',
          description: 'Law window student scientist between news receive. Sign require point.',
          price: '0.00',
          author: '23f1a20asdfsa9-8175-4aasdfdsaf54-9a42-27fesadfdsaff258fc86',
          place: 3,
          placeUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/places/3/',
          imagesUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/story-images/?place=3',
          titleImage: 'http://localhost:8000/media/story_media/example_jJiJGMr.jpg'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: 'Test',
          description: 'sdfdsdsfdsf',
          price: '0.08',
          author: '23f1a209-817sdfdsf5-4a54-9a42-27fef25sadfds8fc86',
          place: 1,
          placeUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/places/1/',
          imagesUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/story-images/?place=4',
          titleImage: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/stories/?limit=9&offset=0&author=23f1a209-8175-4a54-9a42-27fef258fc86'
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want now to access the data of the PlaceUrl (e.g., containing a name, city etc.) and add the data to the oiginal object. My current approach looks like this. However it feels wrong:

```
const selectStoriesList = (state) => state.story.storyList.results;

export const selectStoriesListView = createSelector(
  selectStoriesList,
  (selectStoriesList) => {
    let preparedStories = [];
    if (selectStoriesList && selectStoriesList.length > 0) {
      const promises = selectStoriesList.map(async (item) => {
        const place = await axios.get(item.placeUrl, tokenConfig());
        return {
          authorUsername: item.author,
          authorNickname: "",
          authorImage: "",
          titleImage: item.titleImage,
          title: item.title,
          place: place.data.name,
          city: place.data.city,
          linkToProfile: "",
          linkToPlace: "",
          linkToStory: `www.ssdfsuy`,
          storyPrice: item.price,
          storyIsBought: "",
        };
      });
      console.log(promises);
      let preparedStories = Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
        console.log(values);
        return values;
      });

      return Promise.all(promises);

      // return Promise.all(promises);
    } else {
      return preparedStories;
    }
  }
);
```

How needs the fetch call to look like? Any hint is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A selector is not the place to perform asynchronous fetching.  It should be a simple selection of data from your store.

What you are dealing with here is a relationship between two entity types: a `story` and a `place`.  You'll want to store the data in your store [in a normalized way](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape), possibly using [createEntityAdapter](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter), so that you can lookup a place by its id.

You can trigger the fetching of the places in multiple ways:

**In the Component**

Return just the place id when selecting a story.  Your story component will render a place component like `<Place id={3}/>`.  That `Place` component will select the place object from the store and use a `useEffect` hook to `dispatch` a "request place" action for its id.

**In the Thunk**

The [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) action which you use to fetch the stories can `dispatch` additional actions through the [`thunkAPI` argument](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) of the payload creator function.  Or it can perform multiple API requests and return the data in a single action containing both the places and the stories.

Here's the code for that last idea, though I actually prefer the component-based approach.

```
import {
  configureStore,
  createAsyncThunk,
  createEntityAdapter,
  createReducer,
  createSelector
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
import { uniq } from "lodash";

const tokenConfig = () => ({});

const placesAdapter = createEntityAdapter();

const storiesAdapter = createEntityAdapter();

export const placeSelectors = placesAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) => state.place
);

export const storySelectors = storiesAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) => state.story
);

const fetchStories = createAsyncThunk(
  "fetchStories",
  async (_, { getState }) => {
    // fetch the stories
    const storyRes = await axios.get("/api/v1/stories/", tokenConfig());
    const storyData = storyRes.data;
    // array of place ids for each story
    const placeIds = storyData.results.map((story) => story.place);
    // find which place ids are already in the state and can be skipped over
    const loadedPlaceIds = placeSelectors.selectIds(getState());
    // filter out duplicates and already loaded
    const idsToFetch = uniq(
      placeIds.filter((id) => !loadedPlaceIds.includes(id))
    );
    // fetch all places
    const places = await Promise.all(
      idsToFetch.map((id) => axios.get(`/api/v1/places/${id}/`, tokenConfig()))
    );
    // return your data
    return {
      places, // an array of place objects
      storyData // the story data
    };
  }
);

export const storiesReducer = createReducer(
  storiesAdapter.getInitialState({
    storyList: {
      count: 0,
      next: null,
      previous: null,
      ids: []
    }
  }),
  (builder) =>
    builder.addCase(fetchStories.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      const data = action.payload.storyData;
      // save all of the stories
      storiesAdapter.upsertMany(state, data.results);
      // save the list, but with just the ids for the stories
      state.storyList = {
        ...data,
        ids: data.results.map((story) => story.id)
      };
    })
);

export const placesReducer = createReducer(
  placesAdapter.getInitialState(),
  (builder) =>
    builder.addCase(fetchStories.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      // save all of the places
      placesAdapter.upsertMany(state, action.payload.places);
    })
);

export const selectStoriesListView = createSelector(
  // select the list of story ids
  (state) => state.story.storyList.results,
  // select the stories
  (state) => state.story.entities,
  // select the places
  (state) => state.place.entities,
  // combine all
  (ids, stories, places) => {
    // map ids to objects
    const storyObjects = ids.map((id) => stories[id]);
    // reformat
    return storyObjects.map(({ author, titleImage, price, title, place }) => {
      // get the place from id
      const { name, city } = places[place];
      return {
        authorUsername: author,
        authorNickname: "",
        authorImage: "",
        titleImage,
        title,
        place: name,
        city,
        linkToProfile: "",
        linkToPlace: "",
        linkToStory: `www.ssdfsuy`,
        storyPrice: price,
        storyIsBought: ""
      };
    });
  }
);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    story: storiesReducer,
    place: placesReducer
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Linda, thank you so much for your reply and the links you provided, you really helped me a lot in understanding how to handle data!